# React how to keep rendered components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a grid using *divs* in React. My `Main` component has a `Settings` component and a `Boxes` component.

[image]

Changing the value inside `Settings` will update a state value inside `Main`, which is passed to `Boxes`. Updating this value inside `Settings` will cause `Boxes` to rerender because it uses the state value of `Main`.

Since the amount of boxes doesn't change, I would like to only change the width and height of each individual box with JavaScript. Re rendering isn't necessary in this case.

I've tried to implement my width/height changing code in `shouldComponentUpdate` but this makes it so the boxes don't render at all and throws this error: **Warning: Boxes.shouldComponentUpdate(): Returned undefined instead of a boolean value. Make sure to return true or false.**

So my question is: how can i keep these boxes rendered without having to re render, since updating the column count will only change width and height of each box?

Current implementation of shouldComponentUpdate:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {

    let boxSize = this.state.wrapperWidth / this.props.columns;
    document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('width', boxSize+"px", null);
    document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('height', boxSize+"px", null);
}
```

Comment: What is your current implementation of the `shouldComponentUpdate` method?

Comment: Adding return true; to shouldComponentUpdate resolves the error, but still rerenders all the rendered boxes

Comment: That's the point if you return `true` it should re-render, if you return `false` it should not re-render. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: what's wrong with rerendering? Why do you want to prevent it? I don't see it as a problem in this case but setting the style like this `document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('width', boxSize+"px", null);` might be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I want to prevent re rendering because if the amount of columns is too high, it will be laggy since it has to render a lot of divs. This is the reason why I'm keeping the already rendered divs and changing width and height with JavaScript. In what case would this be a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: it's a maintenance nightmare because your code depends on a particular order of stylesheets in the DOM and a specific order of rules in the stylesheet. You need to always remember to keep it as is or your code breaks. This relation is too fragile. A better way would be to create css custom properties for width and height that live in a css class associated with boxes and change them instead.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a component receives props, it will render again. So when the state of your `Main` component is changed, it will trigger a render of `Main` which will inevitably pass props to `Boxes` and will trigger a render.

However you can use `PureCompoonent` to prevent rendering a component if the new props it received is the same as old props.

PureComponent does a shallow comparison of previous props and prevents re-render if the props are not changed.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Boxes extends PureComponent {
  ... your commponent code
}
```

You can read more on PureComponent here - [Official React Docs - PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)